# Extract specific HTML text using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: html, filter, nodes

```
<table class="result" summary="Summary Description.">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th scope="col" class="firstcol">Column 1</th>
    <th scope="col">Column 2</th>
    <th scope="col">Column 3</th>
    <th scope="col" class="lastcol">Column 4</th>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
    <td class="firstcol">Text 1</td>
    <td>Text 2</td>
    <td>4Text 3</td>
    <td class="lastcol">Text 4</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

The part of the HTML Im interested in looks like this.  I want Text 1, Text 2, Text 3 and Text 4. Using HTMLAgilityPack, how can I extract that data? I google and checked this site but didnt find something that matched my scenario exactly.

```
        if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode text in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(???)
            {
                ???
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        var html = @"<table class=""result"" summary=""Summary Description.""> <tbody> <tr>     <th scope=""col"" class=""firstcol"">Column 1</th>     <th scope=""col"">Column 2</th>     <th scope=""col"">Column 3</th>     <th scope=""col"" class=""lastcol"">Column 4</th> </tr> <tr class=""even"">     <td class=""firstcol"">Text 1</td>     <td>Text 2</td>     <td>4Text 3</td>     <td class=""lastcol"">Text 4</td> </tr> </tbody></table>";
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        var textNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//tr[@class='even']/td/text()").ToList();
        foreach(var textNode in textNodes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(textNode.InnerText);
        }
```

Comment: Works like a dream! Thank you very much.

Comment: A follow up question. If there is also a class called "odd", and I want to have a list as they are in the source (Even, Odd, Even, Odd Etc). How would I Write the question then? Today I just saved  the "odd" to a second list by exchanging the word "even" to "odd", and then added the second list to the first list. But then they will have the wrong order since it will have all the "even" in the beginning and all the "odd" in the end.

Comment: What if they are dynamic as in my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018750/how-to-use-htmlagilitypack-to-extract-html-data