# How to use HTMLAgilityPack to extract HTML data

Tags: c#, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

I am learning to write web crawler and found some great examples to get me started but since I am new to this, I have a few questions in regards to the coding method.

The search result for example can be found here: [Search Result](http://www.nysed.gov/coms/op001/opsc2a?profcd=67&plicno=001475&namechk=WIL)

When I look at the HTML source for the result I can see the following:

```
<HR><CENTER><H3>License Information *</H3></CENTER><HR>                                                                       
<P>                                                                                                                           
       <CENTER> 06/03/2014 </CENTER> <BR>                                                                                     
<B>Name : </B> WILLIAMS AJAYA L                     <BR>                                                                      
<B>Address : </B> NEW YORK            NY                                          <BR>                                        
<B>Profession : </B> ATHLETIC TRAINER                          <BR>                                                           
<B>License No: </B> 001475 <BR>                                                                                               
<B>Date of Licensure : </B> 01/12/07      <BR>                                                                                
                                                                                                                                <B>Additional Qualification : </B>     &nbsp; Not applicable in this profession                       <BR>                    
<B> <A href="http://www.op.nysed.gov/help.htm#status"> Status :</A></B> REGISTERED                                        <BR>
<B>Registered through last day of : </B> 08/15      <BR>
```

How can I use the HTMLAgilityPack to scrap those data from the site?

I was trying to implement an example as shown below, but not sure where to make the edit to get it working to crawl the page:

```
private void btnCrawl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie in shellWindows)
            {
                filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( ie.FullName ).ToLower();

                if ( filename.Equals( "iexplore" ) )
                txtURL.Text = "Now Crawling: " + ie.LocationURL.ToString();
            }
            string url = ie.LocationURL.ToString();
            string xmlns = "{http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}";
            Crawler cl = new Crawler(url);
            XDocument xdoc = cl.GetXDocument();
            var res = from item in xdoc.Descendants(xmlns + "div")
                      where item.Attribute("class") != null && item.Attribute("class").Value == "folder-news"
                      && item.Element(xmlns + "a") != null
                      //select item;
                      select new
                      {
                          Link = item.Element(xmlns + "a").Attribute("href").Value,
                          Image = item.Element(xmlns + "a").Element(xmlns + "img").Attribute("src").Value,
                          Title = item.Elements(xmlns + "p").ElementAt(0).Element(xmlns + "a").Value,
                          Desc = item.Elements(xmlns + "p").ElementAt(1).Value
                      };
            foreach (var node in res)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(node.ToString());
                tb.Text = node + "\n";
            }
            //Console.ReadKey();                   
        }
```

The Crawler helper class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace CrawlerWeb
{
    public class Crawler
    {

        public string Url
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public Crawler() { }
        public Crawler(string Url)
        {
            this.Url = Url;
        }
        public XDocument GetXDocument()
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb doc1 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
            doc1.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (conpatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc2 = doc1.Load(Url);
            doc2.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
            doc2.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
            doc2.OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("html").OuterHtml);
            return xdoc;
        }
    }
}
```

`tb` is a multiline textbox... So I would like it to display the following:

`Name` `WILLIAMS AJAYA L`

`Address` `NEW YORK NY`

`Profession` `ATHLETIC TRAINER`

`License No` `001475`

`Date of Licensure` `1/12/07`

`Additional Qualification` `Not applicable in this profession`

`Status` `REGISTERED`

`Registered through last day of` `08/15`

I would like the second argument to be added to an array because next step would be to write to a SQL database...

I am able to get the URL from the IE which has the search result but how can I code it in my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This little snippet should get you started:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string html = client.DownloadString("http://www.nysed.gov/coms/op001/opsc2a?profcd=67&plicno=001475&namechk=WIL");
doc.LoadHtml(html);

HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div");
```

You basically use the `WebClient` class to download the HTML file and then you load that HTML into the `HtmlDocument` object.  Then you need to use XPath to query the DOM tree and search for nodes. In the above example "nodes" will include all the `div` elements in the document.

Here's a quick reference about the XPath syntax: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I am also using a Crawler class, which I don't need than?

Comment: No not really.  The snippet I posted takes care of loading the HTML file from the url into an HtmlDocument which is ready for parsing with an XPath query.  If you want to abstract that code into a separate crawler class, go ahead :-)

Comment: I think I want to go the easy route :)... So how will it know which DIV I want because there are multiple DIVs on the page.

Comment: To get the DIV which holds the information you need, you can do this:
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='content_column']");

Comment: I get 7 errors... Few of them are: `The type 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument' has no constructors defined` and `The type or namespace name 'HtmlNodeCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` I did import HtmlAgilityPack in my reference.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge, you need to use `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument`, not `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument`. Are you creating a WinForms app? You should have told us that.

Comment: Yeah I am still learning the whole process. I am creating a WinForm app so it's an app rather than a web page. I used what you mentioned, and it worked fine but my app freezes for sometime before I can do anything. I am just looking to extract some data from the page and save it to a string array which will change to moving to a table in the future. Isn't there an easier way?

Comment: Your app freezes because the DownloadString() method is blocking, i.e not asyncronous.  You can use DownloadStringAsync and use a callback function to make the Download happen in a new thread and therefore not block your app's UI thread.